# Adding multiple defined variables to the same list PYHTON

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to add several defined random variables to the same list but when I run it, it groups them into individual lists:

```
inner_list=[]
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=15, size=1).clip(0).astype(int).tolist()
inner_list.append(a)
b = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale = 10, size=1).clip(0).astype(int).tolist()
inner_list.append(b)
c = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale = 15, size=1).clip(0).astype(int).tolist()
inner_list.append(c)
d = np.random.normal(loc=22, scale = 12, size=1).clip(0).astype(int).tolist()
inner_list.append(d)
print(inner_list)
```

But when I run it, it results in:

```
[[11], [14], [11], [26]]
```

How can I group them within the same list?

Comment: @alexpdev Just note each of the variables is calculated differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extend` rather than `append`.

```
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=15, size=1).clip(0).astype(int).tolist()
inner_list.extend(a)
```

Comment: This would create one top level list.  I think op wants one top level and one inner.